# How can i detect if i clicked on treeView1 item if the item is a file or a directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Download")
            {
                // if download selected start download file or directory.
                // to check if selected directory to download whole directory with sub directories and files
                // if selected file to download only file.
            }
        }
```

I can add to the ContextMenuStrip more menus like "Download File"and "Download Directory"
But i thought to make one download option and if i selected it on a directory i download the whole directory if on file download only the file.

The question is how do i know if when i click on Download if the item is directory or a file ?

Comment: Is TreeView data populated by you?

Comment: dotnetstep yes. In the treeView1 i have a tree of nodes of my ftp content directories and files.

Comment: Each treeNode as property called Tag. If you set this property during populating treeView you can identify later on that it is directory or file.

Answer (score 1):

There is `object sender` parameter which is `MenuItem`.

Cast sender to `MenuItem` and check if it is file or directory (check icon or other properties).

I'm not sure about `MenuItem` because I'm not familiar with WinForms